# finding global minimum by data instead of optimization algorithms

Tags: regression, optimization

I have a datasets containing `features` and a `response`. I want to find the global minimum in this dataset. One way is to estimate the relationships among data by a `regressor` and then use optimization algorithms like `PSO` or `GA`.

I am confused because I think ones can find the minimum of responses and report its features as global minimum!

is there any difference between these two ways?

Comment: Hint: fit the $(x,y)$ data $(-2,4), (-1,1),(1,1), (2,4)$ with a quadratic function $y=\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$.  What is its minimum on the interval $[-2,2]$ and how does it compare with the smallest value of $y$ in the data?

Comment: @whuber thanks got it. you mean maybe the minimum is not exactly as same as the generated responses.

Comment: That's right.  This is the principle behind response surface analysis.  The idea is that you can control some variables in the lab while searching for the best response, but you're not going to be lucky enough to set them *exactly* to the best values.  It therefore pays to estimate where the best settings are rather than just settling for the best settings you have seen so far.  This gains in importance as the number of independent variables increases, because in higher dimensions the best response can be substantially better than any of your observed responses.